# FlexBox - making a speecific layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I'am new in FlexBox and it is a little bit confusing for me. Could you please help me create that layout:

[image: My layout]

All I have now is:

```html
<div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px">
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
    <div>
        <div fxFlex="25%">title</div>
        <div>text</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div fxFlex="25%">title</div>
        <div>text</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px">
    <div>
        <div fxFlex="25%">title</div>
        <div>text</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div fxFlex="25%">title</div>
        <div>text</div>
    </div>
    <div>image</div>
</div>
```

I dont know how to set flex in this example. I want to have all "text" in one line (column) and image only in this second part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I could come up with. If you need any tweaks, please let me know in the comment section below.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.separate-columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 50%;
}

th {
  width: 250%;
  text-align: left;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="separate-columns">
    <div class="container">
      <h4>TITLE</h4>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h4>TITLE2</h4>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.tinymce.com/images/glyph-tinymce@2x.png" alt="Example">
</div>
```

Comment: Ty for answer. It's quite good solution but as You can see on snippet the image is between 2 section and I would like to make it visible only in the second section (it's going to be visible when TITLE2 apperas)